# ASP.NET mvc without using the framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

I have a Default.aspx Page which handle on `Page_Load` event all the logic and present the page.
So, there's one html page. BUT, I have two main CSS files and the user can choose between those two themes.

The thing is, it got too complicated, so what I want to do is to create two `Page`s which will be the `View`s, and one `Model` to handle the request **and route to the proper `View`**.

What is the best practice for this scenario?
Thanks.

### EDIT:

The difference between the themes doesn't amount in colors/sizes, but in the layout of the elements etc. So, in this point it's necessary to me **shifting to two different Pages.**

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to switch the css files, not the views. If you have 2 css files, using your solution with let's say 100 pages, you'll create 200 views? What if you wanted to have 3 themes to choose from?

CSS isn't a content property of your website, it's just a styling. You really shouldn't have different routes for different styling, it's a SEO suicide.

This is a nice example how your layouts should be done in MVC3 with razor http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx

And one more thing - model really shouldn't know ANYTHING about the view. That is the job for the controller. That's the whole point of MVC - separation.

Comment: the problem is the html layout is slightly different, so it's becoming a challenge to control the two. Shifting to two `Page`s is necessary

Comment: @CreativityParalyze, if it is "necessary" for you, than you've clearly done something wrong... Your architecture needs to support such changes without any problematic core modifications. There's really not much we can do for you now. I suggest you to rethink the whole structure of your website with these changes on mind. It might look like a lot of work to you, but in the long run it's definitely worth it.

Comment: the two themes must be seperated to two Pages. there's substantial difference between them. two views needed

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly, but wouldn't this work for you:

```
<link href="<%=Session["CssFile"].ToString() %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```